# WinForms Touchpad Scrolling

Tags: winforms, scroll, touchpad

I'm working on a winforms application meant for touchpads and would like the user to be able to scroll through the contents by swiping their finger across the screen. I see that windows (at least windows 7) has this behavior built in for any scrollable control. However the control I'm trying to scroll is a third party control that went ahead and made its own scrollbar elements, so this built in behavior is lost.

I could get the same behavior by placing that third party control in a panel, and letting that panel handle the scrolling. However when the user swipes on that control, its containing panel doesn't hear those events and scrolling never takes place.

Are they any resources on how windows handles touchpad scrolling, or how I could make a panel respond to touchpad swipes when the cursor is inside one of its child controls?

Comment: Does the regular mouse wheel work with this 3rd party control?

Comment: Winforms deals with legacy Windows, mostly.  WM_TOUCH is definitely not legacy.  Winforms doesn't stop you from using it but you'll have to drop down to WndProc().  SDK guide is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317321%28VS.85%29.aspx